# How can I obtain PDF from Orcad .dbk?

Tags: schematics, orcad

How can I obtain a PDF file from a schematic in Orcad (with .dbk extension)? Is there a converter?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution may be to use a PDF virtual printer. This allows any Windows software with a "print" function to print to a PDF instead of paper. I've had good luck with [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php), but there are [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Creators_4), including [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/), [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com/), [pdf 995](http://www.pdf995.com/), and [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/).

I've never used any of these specifically with Orcad, but I don't see any immediate reason why they shouldn't work. They definitely work well with Ultiboard, Multisim, MS Word, and a number of other applications.

Of course, this assumes you have a working copy of Orcad. If you don't, there appears to be a viewer available for download from Cadence [here](http://www.cadence.com/products/orcad/pages/downloads.aspx#viewreader). I haven't tried it, unfortunately.

Comment: I wrote and deleted the same basic answer in a comment... my speculation is that the OP doesn't have Orcad, but wants to be able to view a schematic that is only available in native format

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and edited my answer just as you were posting your comment. :-)

Comment: I've used PDFCreator for several years now. Can't complain. Free and works very well.

Comment: cutepdf is free for commercial use. Most free PDF writers are free for personal use only.